# Foreign key validation rule in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I have `parent_id` that can have **NULL** value - default sets to **0**.

**Model**

```php
...
[['parent_id'], 'integer'],
[['parent_id'], 'default', 'value' => 0],
[['parent_id'], 'exist', 'targetAttribute' => 'id', 'skipOnEmpty' => true],
...
```

But *exist* rule didn't work.

What I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Today I removed the following rule and it works:

```php
...
[['parent_id'], 'default', 'value' => 0],
...
```

But what do I do if want to change the default to other value?

Comment: You should define `targetClass` and `targetAttribute` for that rule. `[['parent_id'], 'exist', 'targetClass' => 'app\models\Parent', 'targetAttribute' => 'id', 'skipOnEmpty' => true],`

Comment: I have `targetAttribute`, `targetClass` is same model by default.

Comment: Can I ask why do you have both `NULL` and `0` as possible values for this column? Don't they mean the same thing?

Comment: Not both, if I create new record I didn't set `parent_id` so it is **NULL**, but into database set to default value - 0.

Comment: What do you mean "didn't work"? Allows to insert rows with not existent parent id? Or throws some exception? Have you tried to change the order of rules (move rule `default` at the end)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the order of rules:

```
[['parent_id'], 'integer'],
[['parent_id'], 'exist', 'targetAttribute' => 'id', 'skipOnEmpty' => true],
[['parent_id'], 'default', 'value' => 0],
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

I didn't think about rule order.